# How to stop Sylpheed from displaying inline text attachments?

Tags: sylpheed

By default Sylpheed display inline all text attachments. I would like to disable this. In 'Common Preferences' there is an option only for images.

Answer (score 0):

From the [FAQ](http://sylpheeddoc.sourceforge.net/en/faq/faq.html):

> 1.31.
> Are there any plug-ins extending standard Sylpheed functionality?
>
> As of Sylpheed 3.1, there is an Attachment Tool Plug-in distributed with the Sylpheed source code and available under plugin/attachment_tool/. Its only function is to remove attachments from selected messages and is provided more or less as a technology preview. More plug-ins are planned since Sylpheed 3.0, released in early 2010, and later supports a plug-in interface. In the future, some of the Sylpheed features will be re-implemented as plug-ins, and, moreover, various other plug-ins will be released.
>
> There is a page on the Sylpheed website dedicated to the plug-in interface. Additionally, the PLUGIN.txt file distributed directly with Sylpheed can provide you with some basic information on the topic.

this appears to mean that you just need the (rather than a XD) plugin.

Comment: Thanx for the response but I can't find something to answer my question. The attachement_tool only remove attachments.

Comment: Then you unfortunately have to write your own plugin, look at their documentation (also linked to in the FAQ).